# Is there a way to control the order of child entity, when using one-to-many relationhips?

Tags: java, android, android-room

According to https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/relationships

We can have one-to-many relationships

```
public class UserWithPlaylists {
    @Embedded public User user;
    @Relation(
         parentColumn = "userId",
         entityColumn = "userCreatorId"
    )
    public List<Playlist> playlists;
}

@Transaction
@Query("SELECT * FROM User")
public List<UserWithPlaylists> getUsersWithPlaylists();
```

---

In both entity `User` and `Playlist`, we have added a column named `sort_key`

The purpose is, when we perform query, we can do the following

```
@Transaction
@Query("SELECT * FROM User order by sort_key")
public List<UserWithPlaylists> getUsersWithPlaylists();
```

We can control the order of `List<UserWithPlaylists>`.

But, how about `List<Playlist> playlists` child entity?

How can we define a custom query for child entity `Playlist`, so that we can have control over `List<Playlist> playlists` ordering?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> How can we define a custom query for child entity Playlist, so that we can have control over List playlists ordering?

I'm afraid there is no out-of-box way here.

Using **@Relation** annotation all you have is:

- [5 annotation's parameters](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/room/Relation#summary) (**associateBy**, **entity**, **entityColumn**, **parentColumn**, **projection**. None of them has influence on order of child table's items)
- Under the Relation's hood Room uses two queries - first you explicitly write in your DAO

```
SELECT * FROM User order by sort_key
```

and another - for fetching data from the child table (based on type of query's result and on **@Relation** parameters):

```
SELECT * FROM PlayList WHERE userCreatorId IN (<List of users id from the first query>)
```

This query is autogenerated and you **@Relation** annotation has no options to change item's order in it.

Of course, after getting this "unordered" result you can add some post-processing to achieve what you want manually

Comment: So it means there is no default way of sorting data using relation? I have my sort orders inside the Relation table.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure It is possible to add @Query to a field but what i'm sure is that you can use a particular collection to make the order. These are the steps:

1. Make the `Playlist` entity emplements `Comparable` interface, then define the `compareTo` method following the **sort_key** attribute.
2. Instead of list in `UserWithPlaylists` entity, use `SortedSet` or `TreeSet` this particular collection returns items ordered using natural order or Comparator.

Answer (score 2):

You can implement this functionality in two ways :

1) You could use the Hibernate-specific @Sort annotation to perform in-memory (i.e. not in the database) sorting, using natural sorting or sorting using a Comparator you supply. 
For example, assume I have an MyComparator helper class that implements Comparator. Helper class can help you sort by sort_key.
You could change Playlist collection like this:

```
@org.hibernate.annotations.Sort(type = SortType.COMPARATOR, comparator = MyComparator)
public Set<Playlist> playlists;
```

@Sort will perform sorting in-memory once the collection has been retrieved from the database.

2) You can use hibernate's @OrderBy annotation, which lets you specify a SQL fragment describing how to perform the sort.

```
@org.hibernate.annotations.OrderBy("sort_key")
 public Set<Playlist> playlists;
```

Hope that helps..!!