# Sorting child items in Android Room DAO Relations

Tags: android-room

The canonical DAO relation query is this:

```
@Transaction
@Query("SELECT * FROM Playlist")
public List<PlaylistWithSongs> getPlaylistsWithSongs();
```

How do I write this so the songs are sorted?

Something like: `SELECT * FROM Songs WHERE playlist_id = :playlist_id ORDER BY position`

I know I can sort the `List<Song>` that comes back, but I think the database should sort them.

Comment: Does this answer your question - [Is there a way to control the order of child entity, when using one-to-many relationhips?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61995635/is-there-a-way-to-control-the-order-of-child-entity-when-using-one-to-many-rela)

Comment: Yes, it does.  Thank you!